# d3 axis tick(timeDay) issue when scale doesn't begin at the start of the day

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building an axis in d3 with the ticks set to timeDays.

I'm setting up the axis like this

```
d3.axisTop(x).ticks(d3.timeDay).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a %d"));
```

with x being a date scale object set between two dates.

x is created using this function

```
var x = d3
.scaleTime()
.range([100, width])
.domain([startDate, endDate]);
```

I then Draw my axis by using this function

```
axisG
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)")
        .call(xAxisWeekTop);
```

In most cases my users will be looking at multiple days and the tick must appear on the midnight line

My issue is, that when the startDate that I'm creating my domain with does not begin at midnight then I don't get any text for my tick.

I'm guessing this is because my range does not contain the start of the first tick, and there is no date to generate a string for.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation for [time interval offsets](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_offset)? That should help you get the ticks you're looking for. If not, let me know and please edit the question with an example start date. It'd be a easy fix.

Comment: Hi Shashank,
I have a good look through, Many thanks. I think the off set is what I'm going to need.

Comment: Alright. Let me know if you face issues with that. I'll help you out.